# Unable to Display USB serial data on flutter Desktop app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am trying to use this code below to retrieve data serially through a usb port. The code compiles successfully and even builds the executable but doesn't display the data. When the 'print' command is used, the data is displayed on the console which confirms that the data is being received by the program but we are unable to display it in any widget.
Please suggest a solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:serial_port_win32/serial_port_win32.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var ports = <String>[];
  late SerialPort port;

  String data = '';

  void _getPortsAndOpen() {
    ports = SerialPort.getAvailablePorts();
    if (ports.isNotEmpty) {
      port = SerialPort(ports[0]);
      port.open();
      print(port.isOpened);
      port.readBytesOnListen(8, (value) {
        data = value.toString();
        setState(() {});
      });
    }
    setState(() {});
    // setState(() {
    //   ports = SerialPort.getAvailablePorts();
    // });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              ports.toString(),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(data),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                port.close();
              },
              child: Text("close"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getPortsAndOpen,
        tooltip: 'GetPorts',
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```