# How to get serial port data in an event form in flutter windows desktop application

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, serial-port, dart-pub

I am making a windows application which communicates with a custom hardware over serial port (Sends and receives data to/from the device, processes it and displays it on relevant widgets).

I am stuck at the receive part of data. I want a function to be called whenever data is received on a serial port without having to check for it constantly. I am using the [serial_port_win32](https://pub.dev/packages/serial_port_win32) package to communicate with my device.
As far as I understood the package, there is no way to subscribe to serial port receive event and call a relevant function.

I could make an function which gets called by a timer event and reads serial port data, but this does not sound like a good solution.

I have looked at dart stream option. The way I understood it is that, the Stream function's definition will have a code to check if there is some data available available on serial port and yield it, if there is any. But there too I will have to provide some timeout in the read function in case there is no data.

All of the solutions I could think of are not really "event trigger on their type". I am sure there would some elegant way of doing this.

Comment: what about [readBytesOnListen](https://pub.dev/documentation/serial_port_win32/latest/serial_port_win32/SerialPort/readBytesOnListen.html)? the docs say: *"readBytesOnListen can constantly listen data, you can use onData to get data."*

Comment: That should serve the purpose. I do not know how I missed that. It's not working as expected is separate issue though ( faced by [somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747066/unable-to-display-usb-serial-data-on-flutter-desktop-app) else too